# Getting all IPv6 addresses on a Linux server

Tags: c++, linux, ipv6

I'd like to find all IPv6 addresses on all interfaces on a Linux server in a C++ program. I'm looking for the equivalent to `GetAdaptersAddresses()` on Windows.

I want to do the same as `ip -6 addr show` does. How `ip` do this ? strace didn't really enlighten me.

Comment: Any ideas why the [answer by @Goz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3702068/3150802) was deleted?

Comment: probably because it's a link-only answer. Only @Bhargav can tell us the reason